# generalized eigenvalue basis

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $M:V\rightarrow V$ is a liner transformation and $\vec v$ is an eigenvector of $M$ of eigenvalue $\lambda$. Prove that $\vec v$ is an eigenvector of $M \circ M$ of eigenvalue $\lambda^2$.

So would we begin with supposing $M(\vec v)= \lambda^2\vec v$ or do I need to set up a generalized matrix?

Answer (score 1):

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $a$ then $Mv = av$. What is $M^2v = M(Mv)$?

Comment: $M(M\vec v)=M(a\vec v)=a(a\vec v)=a^2\vec v$ ?

Comment: @KellyR and you're done. (why?)

Comment: Because this is what we were trying to prove!\